# How to mass-share a selection of private videos on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I have a lot of privated YouTube videos, the amount clocking in the hundreds. I would like to share all of them with one person, i.e. let only them be able to see all of those hundreds of videos.

YouTube's mass-selection interface doesn't let me share all the videos with anyone, only letting me mass-change all of their visibility between Public, Unlisted, and Private. This is true for both YouTube Studio Beta and Creator Studio Classic.

Adding them all into a private playlist doesn't work, because you can't specifically share a private playlist with anyone.

The closest thing I get is to make all of the videos Unlisted and make the playlist Unlisted, but there is a specific reason I want to make the videos private instead of unlisted.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make all those videos private or add them to a new playlist and make them private there.

Next visit this [YouTube Help - Allow others to view private videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177):

> **About Privacy Settings** ([Video Instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_j3pGmiKvxU)):
>
> **Private videos**
>
> Private videos and playlists can only be seen by you and the **users you choose**. Your private videos won’t appear to others who visit the "Videos" tab of your channel page. They also won't show up in YouTube's search results.
>
> To share a private video:
>
> 1. Go to your [Video Manager](http://www.youtube.com/my_videos) in Creator Studio Classic.
> 2. Find the video you want to share, then select Edit.
> 3. Beneath the "Privacy Settings" drop-down menu, select Share.
> 4. Enter the **email addresses** of people you'd like to share your video with, then select OK.
>
> Comments are not available on private videos. If you want to allow comments on a video that's not publicly available, change the privacy setting to unlisted.

The first link includes instructions for: desktop computer, Android, iPhone & iPad.

The difference between private and unlisted is that you can share an **unlisted** video's URL with other users. The people you share the video with **don't need a Google Account** to see the video. Anyone with the link can also **re-share** it.

Contrary to what is mentioned in some of the comments below you can have **private** videos ***and*** [choose who to share them with](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177#zippy=%2Cprivate-videos).
You can also create a [Brand Account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007?sjid=7547074909878133754-NA) and either use your existing channel or create a new linked channel, transfering the videos to the new channel.

You can add Managers to the new channel, allowing them to access the private videos and have basic management capabilities, if you want them to be able to more than simply view private videos.

The above is applicable to one or more additional people, beyond the creator of the channel.

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't answer the question. The OP wanted to do it in bulk, not one at a time.

Comment: Kit, the word "selection" is in the title; first they select, then they share a mass emailing. You are encouraged to write a better answer, that helps both InfoTeddy and the more than five thousand visitors who visited before your comment.

Comment: I think you understood the words in the question "mass share" to be "share with many people". That's not so: they want to share a mass selection (over a hundred) of videos with a single person. They can't find a way to select many videos and share them all at once. I want to do the same thing, and I can't. In your answer it says 'find the video [singular] you want to share'. You don't show a way to share multiple videos at once. Hence why I don't think you answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Youtube studio interface does not offer a way to directly specify sharing targets when bulk editing videos.

Here's an alternative method to accomplish something similar (but not identical)
These instructions are written for the web interface.

1. In the Youtube Studio interface, select Settings on the left menu.
2. Select Permissions.
3. Click Invite then select "Viewer" as permission.

The invitee will have full read-only access to everything you see in your studio interface.  All of your videos and playlists. They can view any private videos or playlists.